# XUbuntu LightDM login loop

Tags: login, xubuntu, lightdm

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, and I randomly got a login loop upon restarting my PC. The content of my `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` is the following:

```
Greeter connected version 1.27.0 api=1 resettable=false
Greeter start authentication for malek
Session pid=1767: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'malek'
Session pid=1767: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
Seat seat0 changes active session to
Seat seat0 changes active session to 4
```

I did select the save session on restart option, which I only started doing two days ago, and I never had to encounter this problem before.
My home directory and all of the files inside of it belong to malek

I am completely stumped, I don't want to re-install Linux (unless there's a way to do so without loosing your users)

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634).

> Did you end up here after running `sudo startx`? Nevertheless:
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the
>   shell.
>
> Now run `ls -lA`. If you see the line
>
> ```
> -rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
> ```
>
> then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try
>   logging in (you may also need to do the same for for `.ICEauthority`).
>
> Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left:
>   they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.
>
> ```
> drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
> ```
>
> Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.
>
> If not both, I'd recommend you either
>
> 1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
> 2. or uninstall, reinstall it.
>
> Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> until you reach the login screen
>   again, and restart.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chown username:username .ICEauthority` solved the issue for me.

It read as `-rw-------  1 root root` using `ls -lA`, and `chown` returned ownership to my user.

The problem was likely caused by my attempt to install x11vnc for X11 forwarding; it must have modified permissions for that file, which caused the bootloop.

Uninstalling x11vnc and `sudo apt-autoremove` did not fix the issue.